# Python3 Sending a new image to a label

Tags: python-3.x, label

Hi I'm trying to update album art when I click on a button.
Everything works except the code below when updating the image.
The image is downloaded from Spotify and save as 'album.jpg'
The path variable has the full path of the image, the background appears on the screen without the image. The funny thing is, if I put say sp_update(), which causes an error before play_track, the image will appear as I want it. This then stops the play_track from exrcuting.

```
image = Image.open(path)
image = image.resize((150,150))
album = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
self.lblSpotify_Album_Art=Label(sp_wrapper2a, image=album, width=150, height=120)
self.lblSpotify_Album_Art.grid(row=1, column=16, sticky=W, padx=5,columnspan=2)

play_track()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in PhotoImage'

There is bug in PhotoImage which removes image from memory (so it is not displayed) when it is assigned to local variable created in function or class method.

It has to be assigned to a global variable

Gazza7364